# Video display in WPF and DirectShow

Tags: wpf, video, directshow, directshow.net, sharpdx

This is one of those messy real world problems. I have a device that provides two video stream of 1920 x 1080 @ 30 FPS. I have the documentation and the SDK for the video device which is unmanaged, naturally. It support GPUDirect. We have tested a SDK which is a SharpDX/SlimDX/DirectShow.Net type wrapper basically around DirectShow for our purposes. Licensing legal issues may prevent the use of this SDK. Being new to this world I am trying to piece together an alternative solution.

The question is the sample I have appears that they take the frame buffer in a surface and apply that to the input pin of a filter. After that is a mystery. I see the video in a a WPF window, can overlay text etc. is DirectShow the best or most direct way to display streaming video or will I find that using DirectX and shaders using say SharpDX easier?

I understand the question is broad in nature but I believe there are many others who are faced with this myriad of tools but do not have enough experience in this graphics world to make the best choice and look to those who have gone before to nudge us in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Opinion based questions are basically considered off-topic, so I am skipping that part and besides that,

DirectShow and DirectX are working together only at the point of presentation of video. [Video Mixing Renderer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407344) and [Enhanced Video Renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375607) components are utilizing Direct3D to present video. That is, you are supposed to choose the most appropriate for you: you either work with DirectX directly, or you are using DirectShow's "gate" to Direct3D.

Then DirectShow itself, you typically use it when you have a source interfaced as DirectShow filter, or you need to apply other DirectShow filters for processing, or you would like to synchronize video and audio, or you otherwise have a good reason to use capabilities of DirectShow in terms of using available components. If you have a video feed comping from non-DirectShow sources, then you need to deliver that into non-DirectShow destination then you might prefer to not use DirectShow at all. DirectShow and Media Foundation are primary APIs for video streaming and those you mentioned are merely wrappers.

Comment: Thank you, Roman. If I am understanding then DirectShow provides me mixing, rendering, audio and the like. Higher level functions if you will. DirectX is lower level so to speak. To accomplish what I need to accomplish I can the lower level APIs or the higher Level APIs. In reality I could use both. It is situational dependent. I guess in my particular situation is the answer is both.